# How do I access image URL from one django model to another? How do I put it on a template?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using two models `Forum` and `User`.

I wanted to access the url of `User`'s `profile_img` and display it to my template in `Forum`. How should I code this in my `Forum`'s `model.py`?

`User` `model.py`:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    profile_img = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)
```

`Forum` `model.py`:

```
class Forum(models.Model):
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    post_body = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    forum_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Title: {}, dated {}.'.format(self.post_title, self.pub_date)
```

`Forum` `views.py`:

```
def View_Forum(request):
    forum_posts = Forum.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")
    return render(request, "forums.html", {"forum_posts": forum_posts, })
```

Comment: Please add the `Forum` model to your question

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple relation. To get url of an image you need to add `.url` on the Image object. Just use:

```
forum.author.profile_img.url
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I realized the reason why the image does not show up is because there was no image for the certain user in the database.